# Latex Formulas or symbols in table cells using knitr and kableExtra in R-Markdown,

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, symbols, tabular

Thanks to jaySf I was able to create a pdf file containing beautiful tables with footnotes showing formulas and symbols with R Markdown, Latex, `knitr` and `kableExtra` (below his example):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r tab}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(6), v2=runif(6), v3=rbinom(6, 1, .33), 
             row.names=LETTERS[1:6])
kable(df, "latex", align="c", booktabs=TRUE) %>%
footnote(general=c("$a^2+b^2=c^2,$",     
                   "$\\\\sigma^2=\\\\frac{1}{n-1}\\\\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\\\\bar{x})^2;$", 
                   "1,000 \\\\$;", "100\\\\%."),
         number=c("Hello\ there! \\\\textit{Hello\ there!}"),
         footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, 
         escape=FALSE)
```
````

which results in:

[image]

Now I'm struggling with putting symbols or formulas within one of the actual cells of the table. Could someone make an example which shows regular text *and* symbols *and* formulas within one cell? Preferably *also* the same in table title, in one of the column names *and* one in one the row names of the table and with some numbered footnotes referring to information in one of the cells or title or col or row names, I'm dying for an example which has it all! Many many thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure: take note of the argument `escape` passed to `kable`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r tab}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(6), v2=runif(6), v3=rbinom(6, 1, .33), 
             row.names=LETTERS[1:6])

df$v4 <- c('My formula $\\sum_{i=1}^9$')
kable(df, "latex", align="c", booktabs=TRUE, escape = F, caption = '$\\Gamma$') %>%
footnote(general=c("$a^2+b^2=c^2,$",     
                   "$\\\\sigma^2=\\\\frac{1}{n-1}\\\\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\\\\bar{x})^2;$", 
                   "1,000 \\\\$;", "100\\\\%."),
         number=c("Hello\ there! \\\\textit{Hello\ there!}"),
         footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, 
         escape=FALSE)
```
````

[image]

Another example with italic column names and an additional header:

````
```{r, echo = F}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(6), v2=runif(6), v3=rbinom(6, 1, .33), 
             row.names=LETTERS[1:6])
df$v4 <- c('My formula $\\sum_{i=1}^9$')

# italic column headers
colnames(df) <- paste0("\\textit{", colnames(df),"}")

kable(df, "latex", align="c", booktabs=TRUE, escape = F, caption = '$\\Gamma$') %>%
footnote(general=c("$a^2+b^2=c^2,$",     
                   "$\\\\sigma^2=\\\\frac{1}{n-1}\\\\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\\\\bar{x})^2;$", 
                   "1,000 \\\\$;", "100\\\\%."),
         number=c("Hello\ there! \\\\textit{Hello\ there!}"),
         footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, 
         escape=FALSE) %>%
  add_header_above(header = c("\\\\textbf{Results} $\\\\Delta$" = 5), escape = F)
```
````

Comment: Beautiful. This definitely helps a lot of people struggling with tables!

Comment: Dear Martin, would you be so kind to also include an example in which the column names (or even headers above headers) are in italic, symbols or formulas? Many thanks, it would make this page complete!

Comment: Done. Always the same. Just add the raw tex where you need it.

Comment: Uber Geil! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks Martin!! This was so helpful! I've struggled so much with tables and none of the other info I was finding elsewhere was working for PDFs!

Comment: and... for a table in html/revealjs?