# Math kableextra latex

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I have been following the examples on how to include math in cells in KableExtra R markdown, and maybe I am doing something really silly, but I can't seem to get math symbols to work

Following the examples here: [Latex Formulas or symbols in table cells using knitr and kableExtra in R-Markdown,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416492/latex-formulas-or-symbols-in-table-cells-using-knitr-and-kableextra-in-r-markdow)
But I don't seem to get my example right as it still gives me the missing $ at the end of table error.

```
output file: test.knit.md

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.125 \end{tabular}}
```

I am trying to create a pdf document

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Willem"
date: "13 March 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r packages, echo=F, warnings=F, message=F, eval=T}
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
```

Try out the table

```{r summarytable, echo=F, message=F, eval=T}

table <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("LC variable","Small area of significant pixels in the centre","Large area possibly aligning with bushfire affected area.",
"t-test regression model residuals","Slightly lower mean residual ($p\\\\<0.05$) after change (0.5 mm per month)","Lower mean residual ($p\\\\<0.05$) after change (1.5 mm per month)",
"Positive score","0.2\\% of pixels at $p\\\\<0.1$","3.7\\% of pixel at $p\\\\<0.1$",
"Field significance of scores", "Both positive and negative within random distribution", "Positive outside random distribution."
),nrow=4,ncol=3, byrow=T))
kable(table,caption="Summary table of all tests on the two regions ", 'latex',
      booktabs =TRUE, escape=F,col.names = c("Test","Qld" ,"NSW VIC")) %>%
column_spec(2:3, width = "7cm") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")#%>%
  #kableExtra::landscape()
```
````

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: The R-code runs in my case. What is the problem? If you are using Rmd, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I provided that, I have added the rmd yaml header

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$p\\\\<0.1$`? You mean `$p<0.1$`? `\\%˚ is fine though.

Comment: I would like to have p < 0.1 in the text as an equation, or are you suggesting I can just use \\< and don't need the $$ for the equation? I think I tried that but will try again.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that does not work :  ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... & Slightly lower mean residual (p\<
                                                  0.05) after change (0.5 mm...
l.125 \end{tabular}}

Comment: OK, thanks for all your hints, I solved it base don rethinking Martin's hint. Yes, just using $p<0.1$ solved the issue and $p<0.05$, see below for the solution

Answer (score 1):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Willem"
date: "13 March 2019"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r packages, echo=F, warnings=F, message=F, eval=T}
require(knitr)
require(kableExtra)
```

Try out the table

```{r summarytable, echo=F, message=F, eval=T}

table <- as.data.frame(matrix(c("LC variable","Small area of significant pixels in the centre","Large area possibly aligning with bushfire affected area.",
"t-test regression model residuals","Slightly lower mean residual ($p<0.05$) after change (0.5 mm per month)","Lower mean residual ($p<0.05$) after change (1.5 mm per month)",
"Positive score","0.2\\% of pixels at $p<0.1$","3.7\\% of pixel at $p<0.1$",
"Field significance \\% of scores", "Both positive and negative \\% within random distribution", "Positive \\% outside random distribution."
),nrow=4,ncol=3, byrow=T))
kable(table,caption="Summary table of all tests on the two regions ", 'latex',
      booktabs =TRUE, escape=F,col.names = c("Test","Qld" ,"NSW VIC")) %>%
column_spec(2:3, width = "7cm") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")#%>%
  #kableExtra::landscape()
```
````